# how to write Regex expression for URI that starts with /search or equals to /search

Tags: regex, cloudflare

I'm trying to block few things and unfortunately i don't have to many operators. so I'm trying to use the regex expression. but i need help with that. basically I would like block the following:
https://www.example.com/search/12536/limited/*
https://www.example.com/search

there are plenty of other URIs similar to this. that's the reason. I'm just need a regex expression for the URI.path part.

(http.request.uri.path eq "/search" or http.request.uri.path matches "^/search")

Answer (score 1):

yes this regular expression fixed my problem

```
^/search($|/.*)
```